# How to add user to Azure SQL in a way they can browse databases they have access to?

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

**Context**

I have an Azure SQL Server with a few databases inside. I used `CREATE USER [user] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER` on every database to create users for my team members. I grant them `db_datareader` access to every user I've created.

**Problem**

We use SSMS to connect to the database. My team member can access the database if they specify the SQL server URL and the database name in SSMS. However, they can't browse the server to view list of databases they have access.

They would get the `Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'.` error message.

I tried `CREATE LOGIN` and `CREATE USER` in `master` database without assigning any role.

[Browse server option in SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QcTb.png)

An error message will state they don't have the permission.

**Question**

How can I create user/login to Azure SQL Server so the user can view the list of databases they have access when using SSMS? Which is the minimum privilege role I should grant to them in `master` database?

Comment: I think you're kinda smoked unless you give a lot of rights, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-a-list-of-databases-on-an-instance-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16: `If the caller of sys.databases is not the owner of the database and the database is not master or tempdb, the minimum permissions required to see the corresponding row are ALTER ANY DATABASE or VIEW ANY DATABASE server-level permission, or CREATE DATABASE permission in the master database. The database to which the caller is connected can always be viewed in sys.databases.`

Comment: Thanks, @siggemannen. That page is what I've been looking for. And it seems to be the final nail in the coffin.